# Keytool does not ask password (using Facebook lib with android)

Tags: android, facebook, keytool

I run the script below like Facebook said. There is no compiling problem. The problem is it never gives me a password question after process finished and according to facebook documentation it means my keystore path is incorrect. But debug.keystore file is in correct path! C:\Users\KSM45.android

Please let me know where do I make mistake? I just want to login with facebook!

(From documentation page: Also make sure you are using the correct password - for the debug keystore, use 'android' to generate the keyhash. General Rule: If the tool does not ask for password, your keystore path is incorrect.)

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: Which api are you using for fbConnect ?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Comment: it's not about api. it's about keytool and debug.keystore! :(

Comment: Here is another link you can flow this one as well http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your keystore in `~/.android/debug.keystore` then clean your project in eclipse and run your app so the eclipse plugin re-create your keystore.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on WinXP at work today and it didn't work. After few trying I realized this

this is the line i ran and failed:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

the thing is, you should put **"quotation marks"** around your debug.keystore path

just like this:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore **"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore"** | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64